# How to ignore the aggregate and non-aggregate error in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have two tableau data source. One is PO data and another table is GRN data. I need to compare the PO date greater than or less than to GRN date. For that, the first step I make the relationship between two tables and crate the calculation such as PO date > GRN date ( refer below table). But I am getting the Aggregate Error Messages. Plz, advise how to sort this issue.

I followed the below steps but I couldn't

first step:
make the relationship between two tables.

[image]

step 2: create the calculation field on the second table
[image]

Step 3: create the logic calculation field on the first table
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATTR([PURCH_DOC_DATE])>ATTR([SECONDARY_SOURCE].[Postngdate])

It could be that joining these data sources may be better than blending. I appreciate it may not be possible, but joining gives more flexibility.

Check this article on [date scaffolding in Tableau](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/tableau-scaffolding-dates-calculating-deferred-revenue/), it talks about both the joining and blending of dates and may be useful to what you're doing.